# How can I click TouchableOpacity when TextInput is focused (keyboard is open)?

Tags: react-native, expo, touchableopacity

I want to make suggestion for my text input. When I focus on a `TextInput`, a list of title suggestions should appear. While I am typing, I should be able to click on the desired title. The suggestion feature works well. The problem starts when the `TouchableOpacity` can't be clicked while the keyboard is open. However, the `TouchableOpacity` can be clicked when I hide the keyboard first by clicking the back button (If I tap on the screen, it triggers the `onBlur` method, causing the list to disappear). The expected behavior is that `TouchableOpacity` can be clicked while the keyboard is open.

I've been looking for solutions for similar problem but nothing works on my case. The solutions I've tried are `KeyboardAwareScrollView` and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps`

````
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <View style={[{ flex: 1 }]}>
            <Text>Enter Title</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={{ width: '100%', height: 60, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
              autoCorrect={false}
              onChangeText={(val) => {
                handleTitleChange()
                filterTitle(val);
              }}
              multiline={false}
              onFocus={() => {
                setIsTitleFocused(true);
              }}
              onBlur={() => {
                setIsTitleFocused(false);
              }}
              value={Input.title}
            />
            {isTitleFocused && (
              <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height:200}}>
                <FlatList
                  data={filteredTitle}
                  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={{
                        padding: 10,
                        backgroundColor: 'gray',
                        marginVertical: 10,
                      }}
                      onPress={() => onTitleSelected(item?.title)}>
                      <Text style={{color:"white"
                      }}>{item?.title || ''}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                  keyExtractor={(item) => item?.title}
                />
              </ScrollView>
            )}

            <Text>Enter Detail</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={{ width: '100%', height: 60, backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}
              autoCorrect={false}
              onChangeText={(val) => {
                handleDetailChange()
              }}
              multiline={false}
              value={Input.detail}
            />
          </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you don't need the `ScrollView` wrapping the `FlatList`, you can achieve the same behaviour with only the `FlatList`. Then, you can set the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop on the `FlatList` to `'handled'`, which according to the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) will achieve what you need

> the keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by children of the scroll view (or captured by an ancestor)

However, this might still trigger the `onBlur` callback of the `TextInput`, I'm not sure there's much room for improvement there.